# How can you write a function that takes 'm' and 'n' then multiplies 'm', 'n' number of times?

Tags: function, haskell

Here is the problem: Declare type and define a function that takes 2 positive numbers (say m and n) as input, and raise m to the power of n. please use recursion only. Don’t use power operator or library function, just use recursion.

this is my code so far:

> sqr :: Int -> Int -> Int
>
> sqr m n
>
> ```
>    | m > 0 && n > 0   = sqr (m * m) (n - 1)
>    | otherwise        = m
> ```

For some reason, when I do sqr 10 2, it gives me like 1000 or something. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of making a sqr function and forming a pow function with it (if that is what you are trying to do), make a pow function and let sqr be a special case when n = 2.

Answer (score 5):

Let's expand.  Also, your function should be called `pow`, not `sqr`, but that is not really important.

```
sqr 10 2 = sqr (10 * 10) (2 - 1)
         = sqr 100 1
         = sqr (100 * 100) (1 - 1)
         = sqr 10000 0
         = 10000
```

This demonstrates why `sqr 10 2 = 10000`.

Every time you recurse, there's a different value for `m`.  So you need to take that into account some way:

1. Either you write a version that works even though `m` has a different value each time, or,
2. You find a way to keep the original value of `m` around.

I would say that the simplest method uses the fact that `m^n = m * m^(n-1)`, and `m^0 = 1`.

If you're clever, there's a method that's much faster, which also relies on the fact that `m^2n = (m^n)^2`.

### Spoilers

Some of those mathematical formulas I wrote above are actually valid Haskell code.

```
import Prelude hiding ((^))
infixr 8 ^
(^) :: Int -> Int -> Int
-- Do these two lines look familiar?
m^0 = 1
m^n = m * m^(n-1)
```

This is just the infix version of the function.  You can change the infix operator to a normal function,

```
pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow m 0 = 1
pow m n = m * pow m (n - 1)
```

And the faster version:

```
pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow m 0 = 1
pow m n
  | even n = x * x where x = pow m (n `quot` 2)
  | otherwise = m * pow m (n - 1)
```

Comment: +1, but I think you mean "This demonstrates why sqr *10* 2 = 10000."

Comment: I guess I don't understand how to code this. I understand the mathematical equation for this. I am new to haskell and still not used to the whole recursion thing. How can I code this is my function takes two integers?

Comment: Look closely at the two statements: `m^n = m * m^(n-1)` and `m^0 = 1`.  They almost look like valid Haskell code, don't they?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't use recursion (recall the function)

Comment: `m^n` is what your `sqr` function is trying to compute.  @Dietrich is showing you that `m^n` can be defined in terms of `m^(n-1)`, with a base case of `m^0 = 1`.  i.e. `sqr m n` can be defined in terms of `sqr m (n-1)`, with `sqr m 0 = 1`.  That's recursion!

Comment: @user2921302 The function is called `^` (just a single caret), and it recalls itself in the first case.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 separate problems here.  Just write out all the term-rewriting steps to see what they are:

```
sqr 10 2
sqr (10 * 10) (2 - 1)
sqr 100 (2 - 1)
sqr 100 1
sqr (100 * 100) (1 - 1)
sqr 10000 (1 - 1)
sqr 10000 0
10000
```

This will show you one of the problems clearly.  If you don't see the other one yet, try starting with

```
sqr 10 3
```